# Squaring 2**32 into a 128-bit type fails

Tags: c, int128

I would expect the following C code to produce `8, 16` for the first `printf` (it does), and `1, 0` for the second (however, it produces `0, 0`). Why is that? (This is on MacOS on an Intel Core i7.)

```
typedef unsigned long long ll;
typedef unsigned __int128 bigint;

void main() {
  ll q;
  bigint s;
  q = 4294967296ULL; // 2**32
  s = q*q;
  printf("%d, %d\n", sizeof(ll), sizeof(unsigned __int128));
  printf("%lld, %lld\n", s / q, s % q);
}
```

Edit: After modifying the code to what is below, the results are the same (and note: in the original code, I was not trying to print any 128-bit values).

```
void main() {
  ll q;
  bigint s;
  q = 4294967296ULL; // 2**32
  s = q*q;
  printf("%zu, %zu\n", sizeof(ll), sizeof(unsigned __int128));
  printf("%llu, %llu\n", (ll)(s / q), (ll)(s % q)); 
}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong `printf` format strings for `sizeof` and also, I don't think `printf` has support for `__int128`s

Comment: What happens if you explicitly cast `s / q` and `s % q` to `long long`?

Comment: Following up on what @TedLyngmo said, `%lu` is the proper format specifier the return value of `sizeof`.

Comment: It might be worth noting that your types are `unsigned` but you're specifying a signed type in the `printf` format string.

Comment: @DanielWalker I'd say that `%zu` is the proper conversion
specifier for `sizeof` :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, good point.  In practice, they'll probably be the same.

Comment: @DanielWalker In real practice, I've had to go through tons of code to fix it because people made that assumption "back in the day".

Comment: Ah.  Good to know.  I'll be sure to be more careful in the future.

Comment: @DanielWalker On Windows x64, `long` is 32 bits, while `size_t` is 64 bits. This isn't just a theoretical issue.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, ah.  I almost exclusively use Linux so I've never run into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `s = q*q;`, `q` is a 64-bit `unsigned long long`, and the multiplication is performed with 64-bit arithmetic. Since `q` has the value 2<sup>32</sup>, the mathematical product, 2<sup>64</sup>, does not fit in a 64-bit `unsigned long long`. It wraps modulo 2<sup>64</sup>, so the computed result is 0.

Thus `s` is assigned the value 0, and this is what is printed (aside from the problems with the `printf` conversion specifiers noted in the comments).

You can request 128-bit arithmetic by converting at least one of the operands to the desired type:

```
s = (bigint) q * q;
```

Answer (score 2):

In `s = q*q;` the multiplication is done using `unsigned long long`s, not `unsigned __int128`s, so the result overflows. Either cast an operand to `unsigned __int128` or make `q` an `unsigned __int128` from start.

You are also using the wrong conversion specifiers for `printf`. Use `%zu` for `sizeof`. In addition to that, unless gcc has a `printf` extension for printing the 128 bit types, you'll need to find an alternative way of printing it.

Example:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned __int128 ubigint;

void print(ubigint x) {
    // print top 64 bits first and the lower 64 bits last:
    printf("%016" PRIx64 "%016" PRIx64, (uint64_t)(x >> 64), (uint64_t)x);
}

int main() {
    ubigint q;         // correct type
    ubigint s;

    q = 4294967296ULL;
    s = q * q;         // no overflow anymore

    printf("%zu, %zu\n", sizeof(long long), sizeof(ubigint));

    print(s);
    putchar('\n');
    print(s / q);
    putchar('\n');
    print(s % q);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Output

```
8, 16
00000000000000010000000000000000
00000000000000000000000100000000
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

The calculation `s = q*q;` is done in the type of `q` which results in an overflow and truncation to the type of `q`. Then the truncated result is assigned to `s` which has a bigger type.

Cast `s` to the bigger type to force a calculation in the bigger type.

```
s = (bigint)q * q;
```

Or assign the value of `q` to a variable of the bigger type and use this for the calculation.

```
s = q;
s = s * s;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast:

```
typedef unsigned long long ll;
typedef unsigned __int128 bigint;

int main(void)
{
  ll q;
  bigint s,d;
  q = 4294967296ULL; // 2**32
  s = (bigint)q*q;
  d = q*q;
  printf("%lld, %lld\n", (ll)(s / q), (ll)(s % q));
  printf("%lld, %lld\n", (ll)(d / q), (ll)(d % q));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6EKc7WsxW